# Вывод товара в корзине с помощью сессии

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как вывести названия товара в таблице. Есть кнопка купить под каждым товаром

`<form action="cart_add.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="buy-item" value="<?= $key ?>" />
    <button type="submit">Купить</button>
</form>`

После обрабатываю запрос

```
    session_start();

require_once 'array.php';

$key = (int)$_GET['buy-item'];

if (!isset($key)) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_cart'] = [];
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_cart'][$key])) {
    $_SESSION['user_cart'][$key] = 1;
} else {
    $_SESSION['user_cart'][$key]++;
}
```

Вопрос такой, как мне теперь вывести это все в таблицу а другой странице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['user_cart'] as $key => $quantity) {
    // здесь с помощью $key получаешь название товара оттуда, где оно хранится
}
```